# Try to reverse Line with pointers in C

Tags: c, input, line, reverse

I get error when  I use pointer to reverse function , when I try to call to the reverse function, and than to print it. pointer send error message . So i was tried to get change some code , but it helpless.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
    char *p1, *p2;

    if(!str) {return NULL;}
    printf("%s",__LINE__); //checking
    for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
    {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
    }
    printf("%s",str);  //checking
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str ;
    printf(" Please enter string \n");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    printf("%s\n", strrev(*str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sharing what the error message would be useful too. For all we know it's "compiler doesn't like your hair color".

Comment: You should probably read up on pointers.

Comment: The xor code to swap values is cute but not particularly sensible.  Use a simple swap: `char t = *p1; *p1 = *p2; *p2 = t;` instead.  Also, calling `printf()` when `strrev()` can return a NULL pointer is not reliable.  Some systems will handle a NULL OK; others will not, and are not required to by the C standard.

Comment: @Marc, there is _no_ mention of hair-colour-defined behaviour in the ISO C standard. This sort of misinformation doesn't do _anyone_ any favours :-)

Comment: Also, `printf("%s",__LINE__);`... I thought `__LINE__` evaluated to an integer not a string...

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> char *str ;
> scanf("%s", &str);
> ```

1. You never allocate memory for `str`. Try `malloc` or better yet, use an array in the first place
2. You need to drop the `&` from the `scanf` line

Comment: so what I gonna do.. catch memory by malloc() or change to array??

Comment: @DimaShifer: you can do either; changing to an array is simpler.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to allocate some memory, eg. `char str[256];`.  However, using `scanf` is dangerous, as it does not check the length of the receiving buffer and thus could overflow the receiver.  A safer alternative is to use `fgets()`, which takes a length parameter for the string.

Comment: @gavinb You can try `scanf("%255s", str)` to make it safer.

Answer (score 2):

You have quite a few issues there.

**1/** First, you do not allocate any storage for your string. This could be fixed with a simple `char str[128];` depending on your size requirements. This will also mean that the NULL check is unnecessary and you don't have to worry about later printing (or trying to print) a NULL pointer - change the function contract so that this is explicitly forbidden.

**2/** Next, don't *ever* use `scanf("%s")` (ie., with an unbounded string format specifier) - it's an easy pathway to buffer overflow problems. If you want a robust input function with overflow checking see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

In any case, `%s` scans a *word* rather than a line so, if you enter `"Hello Pax"` (with a space), it will see `Hello`.

**3/** Thirdly, if `str` is a `char*`, then `*str` is a *character,* not a C string. You should be passing `str` to `strrev`, not `*str`. This is true even with the fix in point 1 above.

**4/** The `__LINE__` macro expands to an integral type so won't take kindly to being treated as a character pointer as per the `%s` format specifier. You may want to use `%d` instead.

**5/** The ISO standard reserves all names starting with `str` and a lowercase letter for its own uses, as per `7.31.13 Future library directions` in C11. So `strrev` is not actually a good idea.

**6/** Lastly, the XOR-swap trick is an anachronism that has no place in today's modern environments. It's both unnecessary and may well be slower, given the calculations rather than simple moves of a temporary-variable solution. The correct way to swap to variables is:

```
int t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

Do yourself a favour and ditch that trick. It belongs in the same bucket as Duff's Device :-)

---

Some other issues, though this are more stylistic than anything else (as in I prefer this style), based on quite a few years of teaching programming.

**7/** Most people I've encountered find it easier to understand array indexes rather than pointers since it's easier to think about a character in a string rather than an arbitrary memory location. Seasoned C programmers know there's no difference (both in terms of functionality and, with today's compilers, performance). Hence I tend to use indexes rather than pointers, such as with:

```
char *reverseStr (char *str) {
    char tmpchar;
    int front = 0;
    int back = strlen (str) - 1;
    while (front < back) {
        tmpchar = str[front];
        str[front++] = str[back];
        str[back--] = tmpchar;
    }
    return str;
}
```

**8/** You'll also notice another thing there, the use of more verbose variables like `front`, `back` and `tmpchar`. The compiler doesn't care how big your identifiers are (within reason) and this makes code much more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try to do some changes)))